# Go: Excessive memory usage, memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, go, garbage-collection

I am very, very memory careful as I have to write programs that need to cope with massive datasets.

Currently my application quickly reaches 32GB of memory, starts swapping, and then gets killed by the system.

I do not understand how this can be since all variables are collectable (in functions and quickly released) except `TokensStruct` and `TokensCount` in the `Trainer` struct. `TokensCount` is just a uint. `TokensStruct` is a 1,000,000 row slice of [5]uint32 and string, so that means 20 bytes + string, which we could call a maximum of 50 bytes per record. 50*1000000 = 50MB of memory required. So this script should therefore not use much more than 50MB + overhead + temporary collectable variables in the functions (maybe another 50MB max.) The maximum potential size of `TokensStruct` is 5,000,000, as this is the size of `dictionary`, but even then it would be only 250MB of memory. `dictionary` is a map and apparently uses around 600MB of memory, as that is how the app starts, but this is not an issue because `dictionary` is only loaded once and never written to again.

Instead it uses 32GB of memory then dies. By the speed that it does this I expect it would happily get to 1TB of memory if it could. The memory appears to increase in a linear fashion with the size of the files being loaded, meaning that it appears to never clear any memory at all. Everything that enters the app is allocated more memory and memory is never freed.

I tried implementing `runtime.GC()` in case the garbage collection wasn't running often enough, but this made no difference.

Since the memory usage increases in a linear fashion then this would imply that there is a memory leak in `GetTokens()` or `LoadZip()`. I don't know how this could be, since they are both functions and only do one task and then close. Or it could be that the `tokens` variable in `Start()` is the cause of the leak. Basically it looks like every file that is loaded and parsed is never released from memory, as that is the only way that the memory could fill up in a linear fashion and keep on rising up to 32GB++.

Absolute nightmare! What's wrong with Go? Any way to fix this?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "code.google.com/p/go.text/transform"
    "code.google.com/p/go.text/unicode/norm"
    "compress/zlib"
    "encoding/gob"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/AlasdairF/BinSearch"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

type TokensStruct struct {
    binsearch.Key_string
    Value [][5]uint32
}

type Trainer struct {
    Tokens      TokensStruct
    TokensCount uint
}

func checkErr(err error) {
    if err == nil {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(`Some Error:`, err)
    panic(err)
}

// Local helper function for normalization of UTF8 strings.
func isMn(r rune) bool {
    return unicode.Is(unicode.Mn, r) // Mn: nonspacing marks
}

// This map is used by RemoveAccents function to convert non-accented characters.
var transliterations = map[rune]string{'Æ': "E", 'Ð': "D", 'Ł': "L", 'Ø': "OE", 'Þ': "Th", 'ß': "ss", 'æ': "e", 'ð': "d", 'ł': "l", 'ø': "oe", 'þ': "th", 'Œ': "OE", 'œ': "oe"}

//  removeAccentsBytes converts accented UTF8 characters into their non-accented equivalents, from a []byte.
func removeAccentsBytesDashes(b []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    mnBuf := make([]byte, len(b))
    t := transform.Chain(norm.NFD, transform.RemoveFunc(isMn), norm.NFC)
    n, _, err := t.Transform(mnBuf, b, true)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    mnBuf = mnBuf[:n]
    tlBuf := bytes.NewBuffer(make([]byte, 0, len(mnBuf)*2))
    for i, w := 0, 0; i < len(mnBuf); i += w {
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRune(mnBuf[i:])
        if r == '-' {
            tlBuf.WriteByte(' ')
        } else {
            if d, ok := transliterations[r]; ok {
                tlBuf.WriteString(d)
            } else {
                tlBuf.WriteRune(r)
            }
        }
        w = width
    }
    return tlBuf.Bytes(), nil
}

func LoadZip(filename string) ([]byte, error) {
    // Open file for reading
    fi, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer fi.Close()
    // Attach ZIP reader
    fz, err := zlib.NewReader(fi)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer fz.Close()
    // Pull
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(fz)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return norm.NFC.Bytes(data), nil // return normalized
}

func getTokens(pibn string) []string {
    var data []byte
    var err error
    data, err = LoadZip(`/storedir/` + pibn + `/text.zip`)
    checkErr(err)
    data, err = removeAccentsBytesDashes(data)
    checkErr(err)
    data = bytes.ToLower(data)
    data = reg2.ReplaceAll(data, []byte("$2")) // remove contractions
    data = reg.ReplaceAllLiteral(data, nil)
    tokens := strings.Fields(string(data))
    return tokens
}

func (t *Trainer) Start() {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(`list.txt`)
    checkErr(err)
    pibns := bytes.Fields(data)
    for i, pibn := range pibns {
        tokens := getTokens(string(pibn))
        t.addTokens(tokens)
        if i%100 == 0 {
            runtime.GC() // I added this just to try to stop the memory craziness, but it makes no difference
        }
    }
}

func (t *Trainer) addTokens(tokens []string) {
    for _, tok := range tokens {
        if _, ok := dictionary[tok]; ok {
            if indx, ok2 := t.Tokens.Find(tok); ok2 {
                ar := t.Tokens.Value[indx]
                ar[0]++
                t.Tokens.Value[indx] = ar
                t.TokensCount++
            } else {
                t.Tokens.AddKeyAt(tok, indx)
                t.Tokens.Value = append(t.Tokens.Value, [5]uint32{0, 0, 0, 0, 0})
                copy(t.Tokens.Value[indx+1:], t.Tokens.Value[indx:])
                t.Tokens.Value[indx] = [5]uint32{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}
                t.TokensCount++
            }
        }
    }
    return
}

func LoadDictionary() {
    dictionary = make(map[string]bool)
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(`dictionary`)
    checkErr(err)
    words := bytes.Fields(data)
    for _, word := range words {
        strword := string(word)
        dictionary[strword] = false
    }
}

var reg = regexp.MustCompile(`[^a-z0-9\s]`)
var reg2 = regexp.MustCompile(`\b(c|l|all|dall|dell|nell|sull|coll|pell|gl|agl|dagl|degl|negl|sugl|un|m|t|s|v|d|qu|n|j)'([a-z])`) //contractions
var dictionary map[string]bool

func main() {
    trainer := new(Trainer)
    LoadDictionary()
    trainer.Start()
}
```

Comment: Have you profiled it? http://dave.cheney.net/2013/07/07/introducing-profile-super-simple-profiling-for-go-programs

Comment: I'm profiling it now, and will update.

Comment: OK so profiling it with the nice package you linked to leads to this statement as the culprit of the memory leak: `tokens := strings.Fields(string(data))`. I have split this onto two lines and running again to see if its the `string()` or the `strings.Fields`.

Comment: It's this `string(data)`, specifically inside this it is `CALL runtime.slicebytetostring(SB)` that is leaking.

Comment: Doesn't leak in another test I made, so must be something specific about what I'm doing to the bytes first.

Comment: If you suspect it is a bug, Go official list for questions is here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/Golang-nuts . Go developers will ask you all these questions and more, and fill a bug report if necessary.

Comment: In addition, there is a very good technical page about Go profiling here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/05/10/debugging-performance-issues-in-go-programs

Comment: As far as I know, Fields() will not copy `data` into tokens, it will return slices to the original `data`. So even if you are using only a single token, the entire `data` will remain in memory as long as there is a reference to it.

Comment: Yes, I think that this is it. I've tried to reproduce the leak in a different script and it occurs only when I actually save part of the data. So it looks like it is saving the entire file for each 1 word I save.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58856/discussion-between-siritinga-and-alasdair).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that if you're tokenizing from a large string, to avoid memory pinning.  From the comments above, it sounds like the tokens are substrings of a large string.

You may need to add a little extra in your getTokens() function so it guarantees the tokens aren't pinning memory.

```
func getTokens(...) {
    // near the end of your program
    for i, t := range(tokens) {
        tokens[i] = string([]byte(t))
    }
}
```

By the way, reading the whole file into memory using [ioutil.ReadFile](http://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll) all at once looks dubious.  Are you sure you can't use [bufio.Scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner)?

I'm looking at the code more closely... if you are truly concerned about memory, take advantage of [io.Reader](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader).  You should try to avoid sucking in the content of a whole file at once.  Use io.Reader and the [transform](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/transform) "along the grain".  The way you're using it now is against the grain of its intent.  The whole point of the transform package you're using is to construct flexible Readers that can stream through data.

For example, here's a simplification of what you're doing:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "unicode/utf8"

    "code.google.com/p/go.text/transform"
)

type AccentsTransformer map[rune]string

func (a AccentsTransformer) Transform(dst, src []byte, atEOF bool) (nDst, nSrc int, err error) {
    for nSrc < len(src) {
        // If we're at the edge, note this and return.
        if !atEOF && !utf8.FullRune(src[nSrc:]) {
            err = transform.ErrShortSrc
            return
        }
        r, width := utf8.DecodeRune(src[nSrc:])
        if r == utf8.RuneError && width == 1 {
            err = fmt.Errorf("Decoding error")
            return
        }
        if d, ok := a[r]; ok {
            if nDst+len(d) > len(dst) {
                err = transform.ErrShortDst
                return
            }
            copy(dst[nDst:], d)
            nSrc += width
            nDst += len(d)
            continue
        }

        if nDst+width > len(dst) {
            err = transform.ErrShortDst
            return
        }
        copy(dst[nDst:], src[nSrc:nSrc+width])
        nDst += width
        nSrc += width
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    transliterations := AccentsTransformer{'Æ': "E", 'Ø': "OE"}
    testString := "cØØl beÆns"
    b := transform.NewReader(bytes.NewBufferString(testString), transliterations)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(b)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("token:", scanner.Text())
    }
}
```

It becomes really easy then to chain transformers together.  So, for example, if we wanted to remove all hyphens from the input stream, it's just a matter of using [transform.Chain](https://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.text/transform#Chain) appropriately:

```
func main() {
    transliterations := AccentsTransformer{'Æ': "E", 'Ø': "OE"}
    removeHyphens := transform.RemoveFunc(func(r rune) bool {
        return r == '-'
    })
    allTransforms := transform.Chain(transliterations, removeHyphens)

    testString := "cØØl beÆns - the next generation"
    b := transform.NewReader(bytes.NewBufferString(testString), allTransforms)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(b)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("token:", scanner.Text())
    }
}
```

I have not exhaustively tested the code above, so please don't just copy-and-paste it without sufficient tests.  :P  I just cooked it up fast.  But this kind of approach --- avoiding whole-file reading --- will scale better because it will read the file in chunks.

Comment: `AccentsTransformer` now needs to implement the `Reset()` method. Maybe, `func (a AccentsTransformer) Reset() {}`? Anyways, THANK YOU! for one of the clearest examples around on how to use `Transformer`.

Answer (score 0):

1 How large are "list.txt" and "dictionary"?  If it is so large, No wonder the memory is so large

```
 pibns := bytes.Fields(data)
```

how much is `len(pibns)`?

2 start the gc debug ( do  GODEBUG="gctrace=1" ./yourprogram ) to see if there is any gc happening

3 do some profile like this:

```
    func lookupMem(){
      if f, err := os.Create("mem_prof"+time.Now.Unix()); err != nil {
          log.Debug("record memory profile failed: %v", err)
      } else {
          runtime.GC()
          pprof.WriteHeapProfile(f)                                                                                                                                        
          f.Close()
      }
      if f, err := os.Create("heap_prof" + "." + timestamp); err != nil {
        log.Debug("heap profile failed:", err)
      } else {
        p := pprof.Lookup("heap")
        p.WriteTo(f, 2)
      }
   }

    func (t *Trainer) Start() {      
    .......
      if i%1000==0 {
        //if `len(pibns)` is not very large , record some meminfo
        lookupMem()
      }
    .......
```

Comment: `dictionary` contains 5 million words, which takes up 600MB when the app starts because its stored in a map and maps have lots of overhead, but this does not increase because it is then used as read only. `pibns` contains a list of 300,000 10digit numbers, so it is 3MB in size. Neither of these can use anything close to 32GB of memory. I will check the profile and update, thanks.